# The concept of ordinals

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I am trying to understand this concept and have some difficulties.

For example, can I say that $\alpha$ is the cardinality of $\{1,2,3,...\}=\Bbb N$? And if so, what is $\alpha +1$? I guess it is not the cardinality of $\Bbb N \cup \{\sqrt2\}$ (for example)?

Comment: It is useful (perhaps imperative, in set theory) to think of numbers as sets, and by extension think of all ordinals as sets. Whereas each cardinal number represents an equivalence class of sets under bijection, ordinals represent equivalence classes of *well-ordered* sets under isomorphism.

Comment: Shir, the word you're looking for is 'order-type' rather than 'cardinality.'

Comment: Thank you all. I think that maybe I begin understanding this. Suppose I define a the natural order on the Natural numbers. and then I add $\sqrt2$ to be greater then every natural number. can I say then that the order type of the new well ordered set is $\alpha + 1$?

Comment: @shir: Yes, but we use $\omega$ to denote the order type of $\Bbb N$, not $\alpha$.

Answer (score 10):

Ordinals are not cardinals.

Where cardinals are a notion meant to measure the size of a set in a very raw and structureless sense, ordinals are a notion meant to measure the length of a queue. If you prefer, think of it as the line to the bathroom.

Ordinals refer to a linear order, rather than the cardinality. If $\omega$ denotes the natural numbers with their standard order, $\omega+1$ is the order we have by adding a new element and declaring it larger than all the natural numbers. Then $\omega+2$ would be to add another element on top of that.

Both ordinals $\omega+1$ and $\omega+2$ are countable, that is to say, there is a bijection from each of them to $\omega$, i.e. the natural numbers, but this bijection does not preserve the order itself.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Asaf's response, you asked if $\alpha$ was a cardinal, then what is $\alpha + 1$. Note that cardinal arithmetic is not the same as ordinal arithmetic. So while every cardinal is an ordinal, if you want the successor cardinal of $\alpha$ this is not the same as the successor ordinal of $\alpha$ (as exhibited by the fact that $\omega$ and $\omega+1$ have the same cardinality). The successor cardinal of $\alpha$ is the least ordinal greater than $\alpha$ that is not in bijection with $\alpha$.

Comment: Note that, in cardinal arithmetic, $\kappa+1$ is not the same as $S(\kappa)$.