# Ordinals that are not cardinals

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, ordinals

I am reading Jech's set theory and he defines a cardinal number as an ordinal $\alpha$ (a cardinal) if $|\alpha| \neq |\beta|$ for all $\beta < \alpha$, and he says that all infinite cardinals are limit ordinals. My question is: are there any ordinals that are not cardinals? Although I know that an ordinal describe ordering and a cardinal the size of a set, I am a bit confused here.

Thanks

Comment: There might be better duplicates, but that was the first I found.

Comment: The main point is that an infinite set can be well-ordered in many non-isomorphic ways. And while cardinals measure the size of a set when we ignore *any* structure on the set; ordinals measure how "long" is a particular structure on a set.

Comment: Here are some threads where many words have been minced over cardinals and ordinals: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/988559/622), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/448715/622), and [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/426468/622). There are probably many more around here, but those are three that I found quickly enough.